# How to switch my app from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL to run in Heroku?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I have been reading about this issue that i am experimenting with, and I tried all posible solutions could think of but I cant solve it yet. As the topic says: I have a ruby 1.9.3 app that uses SQLite3 but in production enviorment (Heroku) should use PostgreSQL and I cant switch from one to another.

So, I need to know what I am doing wrong :(

- This is what is written in my config/database.rb file:

*config/database.rb:*

```
case Padrino.env
    when :development then DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://" + Padrino.root('db', "camilo_development.db"))
    when :test        then DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3::memory:")
    when :travis        then DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3::memory:")  
    when :staging       then DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
    when :production  then DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end
```

- This is written in the Gemfile: `gem 'pg', :group => 'production'`
- When I execute `Bundle install` command, the output was: "Your bundle is complete! Gems in the groups staging and production were not installed."
- Feel free to see my repository if you need to see something specific that I forget mention: https://github.com/prieser/camilo

Thanks a lot guys, Regards,
Prieser

Answer (score 0):

At some point you must have done

```
bundle install --without staging production
```

and the bundle config remembers that and won't load staging or production gems.  You can delete the `--without` condition this way

```
bundle config --delete without
```

And then run the bundle install again.

Cheers
Steve